# Use automatic controller routes in Laravel is a bad idea

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm coming From CodeIgniter to Laravel.

So, is a bad idea using automatic routes to all of controllers?

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Should I use this instead creating routes in routes.php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is bad.

Controller::detect() is actually not present in Laravel 4 because it is a bit broken.

detect() will go through your filesystem and return controller files, but this is a bad idea because *the order you define your routes matters*. If you have any nested controllers you will find this breaking very easily.

detect() will also return files in a different order depending on the file system, so this leads to a lot of unpredictability.

I would argue that you should define all your routes any ways, it is a lot easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 5):

One of interesting things about Laravel that CI does not have is that for certain pages, you can route directly to the view without needing a controller at all. Think about static pages like 'About Us'. CodeIgniter would need you to set up a controller + view for that, even though the controller will do barely anything. In case of Laravel, you can route directly to a view in this case.

Setting up routes manually will allow you to set these short-circuited routes.

Comment: Really interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Automatic detection is a bad idea.

You can use routes or use Route::controller('mycontroller') or and array of controllers like Route::controller(array('mycontroller', mycontroller2');

Then you get the benefit, without the autodetect.

Answer (score 1):

in laravel 4 :

you can use Restful Controller like documentation http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

But 
     `Route::controller()` must take two parameters as minimum requirement 
first parameter stands for URL respond to ,and second parameter is name of controller

also

you can write third parameter into `Route::controller()` is an array with names of actions (name of action with HTTP verb )and routes names for this actions

ex:

```
Route::controller('users','UsersController',array(
            'getUsers' =>"listUsers" , 
           ));
```

route name for getUsers action  is listUsers

Answer (score -1):

Below is a good example to follow for CRUD and general purpose routing

type    `php arisan controller:make SampleController`

edit ***routes.php*** and add

```
Route::resource('sample', 'SampleController');
```

Then type
`php artisan routes` to show the newly created routes